# MSBuild task to clone Git repository

Tags: git, svn, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have recently moved my SVN repositories to Git. One of the project using MSBuild to checkout SVN repository during the build process. Now I need to clone Git repository instead of SVN during the build process. I came cross the library https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/tree/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks and couldn't find a proper sample to do this. Can someone please help me ?

This is my SVN MSBuild code.

```
<SvnCheckout
    RepositoryPath="$(SiteSvnRepository)"
    LocalPath="$(SiteSvnCheckOutDir)"
    Username="$(SvnUsername)"
    Password="$(SvnPassword)"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Git/GitClient.cs, probably something like <GitClient Command="clone" Arguments="$(SiteSvnRepository) $(SiteSvnCheckOutDir)"/> and have authentication handled by git's config file?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at this now.